# What is the benefit of a subdomain? ex: uploads.mysite.com -- why should I use it?

Tags: subdomain

I am contemplating if I should set up my subdomains for:
api.mysite.com
uploads.mysite.com

But my question is:
Why should I do this instead of just store files in certain folders like /api or /uploads?

Feedback?

Answer (score 1):

With subdomains you can assign different IP addresses to different hosts running on different machines. It is possible, but harder with URL paths under the same hostname.