# What's the benefit of having a help centre on a separate website?

Tags: user-interface, web, user-experience, google-web-designer

I've noticed that online 'help centres' are often hosted on different website. For example:

https://projector.com/ - This is the main site.

https://support.projector.com/en/ - This is the 'help site'. It has a direct link back to the main website but, it's entirely separate.

I am the owner of some different D2C companies and I want to understand the logic behind this and incorporate it into my businesses if it makes sense.

Thanks
M

Comment: Alright well I think thats just being pedantic and doesn't answer the question of why use a subdomain instead of hosting the help centre on the same website

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the benefit of a subdomain? ex: uploads.mysite.com -- why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653134/what-is-the-benefit-of-a-subdomain-ex-uploads-mysite-com-why-should-i-use-i)